# How to wrap an event listener into Promise to make it synchrounous?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have an array list of image urls. I want to get an image width and height, to do so, I use:

```js
    const url = 'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150'
    const img = new Image()
    img.addEventListener('load', function () {
      const isWide = img.width > img.height
      const isTall = img.height > img.width
      console.log(url, isWide, isTall, img.width, img.height) // <--- WORKS FINE
      img.src = url
    })
```

I have a list of images where I want to extract them all in some one `Promise.all(arrayOfImageUrls)`.

How would I make it Promise so it awaits for all of the urls in the image array to complete ?

Here is my code which does not work, it just ignores the "await" and trigger the function before it was even finished:

```js
const array = [
  "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/650x250",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/650x250",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/150x550",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/510x450",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/800x800"
]

function doSomethingAsync(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const img = new Image()
    img.addEventListener('load', function() {
      const isWide = img.width > img.height
      const isTall = img.height > img.width
      img.src = url
      resolve({ url, isWide, isTall })
    })
  })
}

async function doAsync() {
  const promises = []

  array.forEach(url => {
    promises.push(doSomethingAsync(url))
  })

  console.log('before promise all')
  const results = await Promise.all(promises)
  console.log('after promise all', results)
}
doAsync()
```

Comment: "How to make something asynchronous synchronous?" You don't. Probably you can't, and if you could you really shouldn't. The solution is to level up by embracing asynchronism and learn to work with it, not to level down and hack async operations into sync ones. Now `Promise.all()`, as you are using, seems to be the perfect solution, but you say "it doesn't work". Just saying "it doesn't work" [isn't enough](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) for us to be able to help, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to put `img.src = url` *before* waiting for the images to load, not *inside* the onload handler. You are currently waiting for images with no `src` to load.

```js
const array = [
  "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/650x250",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/150x550",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/510x450",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/800x800"
]

function doSomethingAsync(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const img = new Image();

    img.src = url; // <--- Move this line here

    img.addEventListener('load', function() {
      const isWide = img.width > img.height
      const isTall = img.height > img.width
      resolve({ url, isWide, isTall })
    })
  })
}

async function doAsync() {
  const promises = []

  array.forEach(url => {
    promises.push(doSomethingAsync(url))
  })

  console.log('before promise all')
  const results = await Promise.all(promises)
  console.log('after promise all', results)
}
doAsync()
```

Comment: You're welcome, please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem

Comment: Not sure why (you provided them) but ok

Comment: It solved my problem, thank you Jeremy. I asked you to remove those links because they shouldn't be posted there (secret links, sensitive data)

Comment: Ha, well, they are still visible through the [post edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69403169/revisions)...